# how to do inner join between two tables in sql server 2008r2

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

i have two tables:

```
questionbank table
qustion  answer1  answer2  answer3  answer4  correct_ans  sub_name

result table
username  name  correctanswer totalquestions  percentage  result  sub_name
```

i want to perform inner join between these two so that result read from questionbank table and store in result table how i do it in sql server 2008.please help.

also i have the code for c#:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    @"SELECT COUNT(result.username) AS correct_ans
        FROM result
             INNER JOIN questionbank ON result.Q_id = questionbank.Q_id
                    AND result.User_Ans = questionbank.Correct_Ans
                    AND result.username = " + username + " ");

SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(
    @"SELECT COUNT(Q_id) AS totalquestions FROM questionbank";);
```

Comment: Good formatting is your friend.

Comment: You code appears to contain an `INNER JOIN` - so what's your actual question? Do you get incorrect results or errors? If so, give us the details.

Comment: sql mantra: "Concatenating values into sql is the path to the dark site; concatenation leads to injection, injection leads to pwning; pwning leads to going out of business". Use parameters!

Comment: The downvote isn't from me, but I *expect* it is because you haven't actually told us what the *problem* is - i.e. what doesn't work as expected. Or asked a question.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is basically fine (although the `r.username` should probably be a `where`, not a `join` clause); you **really really** should parameterize, though:

```
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"
SELECT COUNT(r.username) AS correct_ans
FROM  result r
INNER JOIN questionbank q ON r.Q_id = q.Q_id AND r.User_Ans = q.Correct_Ans
WHERE r.username = @username"))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", username))
    // use it; since it returns a single COUNT, we can probably use:
    int correct = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    //...etc
}
```

Other than that: it should be fine. If you aren't seeing matches, then try the query in SSMS, making sure you prepend it with something like:

```
declare @username nvarchar(200) = 'Fred';
```

(or whatever). When filtering on a value like `username`, my immediate thought is "case sensitivity" - SQL Server can be case-sensitive or case-insensitive: it you are configured as case-sensitive, then `'Fred'` does not match `'fred'` or `'FRED'` or `'FrEd'`.

Answer (score 1):

This will give error when you run because after result.username you have to write it like this
result.username = '" + username + "'. don't forget to use ' char before and after username. It is better to use parametered query.
I think you have done inner join is there another problem?